# Origin to screen coordinates directx

Tags: c++, math, directx

I'm working with DirectX (C++) and inside a game i have the coordinates of an object somewhere in a world (x,y,z).

How can i translate the objects coordinates to screen coordinates? I'm particularly interested in Vector3 to Screen positions, if that's even possible?

An example of the coordinates i have is:

```
x=1403.722900
y=2892.604736
z=79.125000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DirectX function you need is D3DXVec3Project

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205516%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

You pass in a D3DXVECTOR3 in world coordinates, along with pointers to the viewport and the various matrices (world, projection, view).  Output of the function is the screen coordinates.

There is also a D3DXVec3Unproject function for going the other direction, from screen coordinates to world coordinates.